# How can we create linkbuttons whose text is data-driven, but whose visibility is controlled from the front-end?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I've made a component based on a mx:TitleWindow that contains linkbuttons that I'm using as a context-menu.

The TitleWindow component contains link buttons like this:

```
[Bindable]
private var _showEmailThis:Boolean = false;

[Bindable]
private var _showApproveThis:Boolean = false;

[Bindable]
private var _showReviewThis:Boolean = false;

<mx:LinkButton id="lnkEmailThis" 
               visible="{_showEmailThis}" 
               includeInLayout="{_showEmailThis}" 
               click="lnkEmailThis_click()" 
               label="Email this!" />

<mx:LinkButton id="lnkApproveThis" 
               visible="{_showApproveThis}" 
               includeInLayout="{_showApproveThis}" 
               click="lnkApproveThis_click()" 
               label="Approve this!" />

<mx:LinkButton id="lnkReviewThis" 
               visible="{_showReviewThis}" 
               includeInLayout="{_showReviewThis}" 
               click="lnkReviewThis_click()" 
               label="Review this!" />
```

This component contains a large number of links and is re-used by multiple modules in the same application.

Within each module, this component is used when a user clicks on a row in a datagrid.

The code looks like this:

In "Requests" module:

```
private function dgRequests_click(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    menu.showApproveThis = true;
    menu.showReviewThis = true;
}
```

In "Performance" module:

```
private function dgPerformance_click(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    menu.showEmailThis = true;
    menu.showReviewThis = true;
}
```

As you can see, the visibility of individual linkbuttons is controlled within each module by setting boolean properties.

If I alter this component to use a renderer, how can I control the visibility of the linkbuttons from the code in each module (there are over a hundred links with different functionality - not every link will be used in each module)? **Note: it is not known from the back-end which grid within which module uses which link. This is set in the front end within each module's actionscript file.**

e.g., if the XML looks like this:

```
<links>
   <link>
      <label>Email This</label>
      <visible>_showEmailThis</visible>
   </link>
   <link>
      <label>Approve This</label>
      <visible>_showApproveThis</visible>
   </link>
   <link>
      <label>Review This</label>
      <visible>_showReviewThis</visible>
   </link>
</links>
```

and I set the Email link to show in the module like this:

```
private function dgPerformance_click(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    menu.showEmailThis = true;
}
```

How do I make it take effect? Is there a way to control the visibility of a linkbutton within an item renderer in a component from the module that uses that component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure I understand your question right. But if you have a component (or a group of 'em) sequentially repeating several times with different properties' values you should use mx:Repeater.

Adobe's [docs on Repeater](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=repeater_3.html)

There is also a live example in [TourDeFlex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex.html) (which I strongly recommend to install and use).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Nek. I've used repeaters as well as lists with item renderers. That's not the difficulty. The component has boolean properties to control whether or not to display each link. To display a particular link, the property on the component that corresponds to that link is set to true in the module (see the click event in the question). Considering this, is it possible to make this component data-driven? It needs to somehow set the boolean values in the component from the data source.

Comment: You can access properties using [].

   yourComponent["_showEmailThis"] = true;

If I'm missing the point again please clarify the task a bit more. :)

Comment: Thanks again for trying to help. I've re-worded the question to clarify what I'm trying to accomplish. Possibly, what wasn't clear before is that the backend doesn't know (for performance reasons) which grid in which module uses which link. This is set within the actionscript file of each module. Thus, this data cannot appear in the XML. The properties of the component are set by each module. So, how can I control the visibility of the linkbutton within the renderer of the component from the module that uses the component?